# If $ f(\theta) $ is differentiable and $ g(x) = f(\theta + ax) $, can we show that $ g'(0) = a \frac{df}{d\theta} $?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

#### Problem

Let $ f(\theta) $ be a differentiable function.

Let $ g(x) = f(\theta + ax) $.

Can we show that $ g'(0) = \left[ \frac{dg}{dx} \right]_{x=0} = a \frac{df}{d\theta} $?

#### Example

It appears to be true when I pick a specific example of $ f(\theta) $. For example take $ f(\theta) = \sqrt{1 + \theta^2} $. Then $ g(x) = \sqrt{1 + (\theta + ax)^2} $.

Then $ g'(x) = \frac{(\theta + ax)a}{\sqrt{1 + (\theta + ax)^2}} $. So $ g'(0) = \frac{\theta a}{\sqrt{1 + \theta^2}} $.

Also $ a \frac{df}{d\theta} = a \frac{\theta}{\sqrt{1 + \theta^2}} $.

So we do get $ g'(0) = a\frac{df}{d\theta} $. But is this true in general? If yes, how do we prove this equation?

#### Attempted Solution

This is what I tried so far.

Let $ u(x) = \theta + ax $. Then $ g(x) = f(u(x)) $. Then $ g'(x) = \frac{dg}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} a$.

Now is there a way to show that $ g'(0) = \left[ \frac{df}{du} a \right]_{x=0} = \frac{df}{d\theta} a$?

Answer (score 1):

You see, $f$ is a differentiable function and $\theta$ is the variable representing the input. $g(x) = f(\theta + ax)$ implies that we pick a constant value of $\theta$. Assume $\theta = \theta_0$, We have

$$\
\frac{dg(x)}{dx} = \frac{df(\theta_0 + ax)}{dx} = af'(\theta_0+ax)
$$

Plugging in $x=0$,

$$\
g'(0) = af'(\theta_0) = \left [a\frac{df(y)}{dy} \right]_{y=\theta_0}
$$

I hope it clarifies now. Note that in your case it was:
$$\
\frac{df(u)}{du} \text{ it's the same thing, with just different input variable name.}
$$